# iPhone, how do I disable / enable a nav button based on table view row selection?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I want to only have my navigation bar select button enabled when a row in my table view is selected.

How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `enabled` property on `UIBarItem` (superclass of `UIBarButtonItem`) to enable/disable it in your table view's delegate's `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` methods.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}
```